# Android: AlarmManager "Missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?" when back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, receiver

I am trying to schedule an alarm to run even when the app is in the background. The code below runs fine if the app is in the foreground. However, as soon as I press the back button I get a "leaked Intent Receiver error" suggesting that I am missing a call to unregisterReceiver(). I tried adding `unregisterReceiver(receiver)` to `onStop()` and `onPause()`, but continue to get the same error. Any help is much appreciated!

Also a side question, if I do finally figure out how to unregister the receiver, will that prevent my alarm from triggering? Thanks.

```
    // Alarm
public void SetAlarm()
{
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override public void onReceive( Context context, Intent _ )
        {
            // code to run when alarm hits
            context.unregisterReceiver( this ); // this == BroadcastReceiver, not Activity
        }
    };

    this.registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter("com.blah.blah.somemessage") );
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.blah.blah.somemessage"), 0 );
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));

    // set alarm to fire 5 sec (1000*5) from now (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
    manager.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000*10, pintent );
}
```

Comment: You should register broadcast receivers in onResume() and unregister them in onPause().  If they're registered conditionally, you should set a flag indicating whether they are registered.  I don't think there's any way to test if a receiver is registered, and unregistering a receiver that isn't registered also throws an exception.  (Great API, Google...)

Comment: Thanks for the info Kevin. The receiver is registered conditionally so I tried setting a boolean to flag when it is registered. Now it is telling me that the receiver I am trying to unregister was never registered. Could something be wrong with my code 'unregisterReceiver(receiver)'

Comment: That lead me to a partial solution. It turns out I had defined 'receiver' privately and needed to change it to public. So now it successfully unregisters receiver onPause. However, my alarm only triggers when the app is in the foreground. Does the receiver have to be registered for the alarm to trigger? If so, how do I keep the receiver active while the app is paused/not in focus?